# How to configure JAXB XJC binding file (with CXF) to generate java DataHandler type with WDSL MTOM?

Tags: jaxb, cxf, wsdl2java, xjc

What do I have to put in the XJC external binding file such that it generates the DataHandler type from a XSD type base64Binary when MTOM is enabled in WSDL?

According to the CXF doc ([enter link description here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html)) it can be enabled by adding "xmime:expectedContentTypes="application/octet-stream" as an attribute to the XSD element of type base64Binary. XJC will then generate the DataHandler type.
BTW: I am not completely sure if this is a specific XJC feature or CXF wsdl2java feature.

How can I realize the same generation of the DataHandler type by external configuration?, as the WSDL file isn't mine and can't be changed. 
I am familiar with the XJC binding file and use it for customization, but don't know how to use this to indicate the MTOM usage.

Answer (score 0):

The following may be of some help:

Apache CXF - MTOM Attachments with JAXB
http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html

Also, see page 64-74 here:
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4884.pdf

Comment: Sending Binary Data Using MTOM/XOP
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/webserv_adv/mtom.html

Handling Binrary Data with Axis2 (MTOM/SwA)
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/mtom-guide.html#3